# Web3 - exception on access public property after changing this property in smart contract

Tags: web3js, contract-development, contract-invocation

i have a public property in my smart contract:

```
bool public isWhiteListed = true;
```

On my node server, I access this property like this, to have a validation for white listing:

```
const whitelisted = await contract.methods.isWhiteListed().call()
```

This is working and returning me the correct value, but after changing the property in the smart contract, the line above, is throwing the exception:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

It looks like, after some time, the call is working again and not throwing any exception. So in summary, I have two questions:

- Is there any limit to call properties / view functions?
- Is the exception caused of a pending transaction or why is the exception throwed? I tested the behaviour on my local machine with ganache. So the smart contract property change is happening immediately.

**Update:**

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    bool public isWhiteListed = true;

    function setWhitelisted(bool _state) external onlyOwner {
        isWhiteListed = _state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the smart contract?  Does isWhitelisted get an argument? Or does is throw if the whitelisting is disabled ?

Comment: @MajdTL, sure, I updated the answer with a lighter version of my full contract. As I said, its just a public property and an external function.

Comment: weird, it is looking good. maybe clean the project and cache and try again :/